# Trouble installing ROS Melodic Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ros

I am trying to install ROS Melodic using the instructions on wiki.ros.org and stumbled upon some problems.

**System software information:**

Operating System: Kubuntu 21.10

KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5

KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0

Qt Version: 5.15.2

Kernel Version: 5.13.0-19-generic (64-bit)

Graphics Platform: X11

### Problem

I have first followed steps from
http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu
and later followed the steps from https://varhowto.com/install-ros-melodic-ubuntu-18-04/#Step_1_%E2%80%94_Install_ROS_Melodic_repo , both with unsuccessful results.

When running `sudo apt update` I am getting:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [110 kB]
Ign:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu impish InRelease          
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Hit:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu impish Release  
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

After trying to install with this line:

```
sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full
```

I am getting:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '1.4.1-0bionic.20211104.025752' (ROS bionic:bionic [amd64]) for 'ros-melodic-desktop-full'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python-rospkg : Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
 python-rospkg-modules : Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
                         Depends: python-catkin-pkg-modules but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-actionlib : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-actionlib-tutorials : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                   Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-bondcpp : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-camera-calibration-parsers : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                          Depends: libboost-python1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                          Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                          Depends: libyaml-cpp0.5v5 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-camera-info-manager : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg (> 0.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python-empy but it is not installable
                      Depends: python-nose but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-class-loader : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libpocofoundation50 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-compressed-depth-image-transport : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                                Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                                                Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-compressed-image-transport : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                          Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                                          Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs3.2 but it is not installable
                                          Depends: libopencv-imgproc3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-controller-manager : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-cv-bridge : Depends: libboost-python1.65.1 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libboost-regex1.65.1 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs3.2 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libopencv-imgproc3.2 but it is not installable
                         Depends: python-opencv but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-depth-image-proc : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libopencv-imgproc3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-diagnostic-aggregator : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                     Depends: libboost-regex1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                     Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                     Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-diagnostic-common-diagnostics : Depends: python-psutil but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-diff-drive-controller : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-dynamic-reconfigure : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-filters : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-gazebo-plugins : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libgazebo9 but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libignition-common but it is not installable
                              Depends: libignition-math4 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libopencv-imgproc3.2 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libprotobuf10 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libsdformat6 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-gazebo-ros : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libgazebo9 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libignition-common but it is not installable
                          Depends: libprotobuf10 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libsdformat6 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-gazebo-ros-control : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libgazebo9 but it is not going to be installed
                                  Depends: libignition-common but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libignition-math4 but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libsdformat6 but it is not installable
                                  Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
                                  Depends: ros-melodic-control-toolbox but it is not going to be installed
                                  Depends: ros-melodic-transmission-interface but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-genmsg : Depends: python-empy but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-genpy : Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-image-geometry : Depends: libopencv-calib3d3.2 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libopencv-imgproc3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-image-proc : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libopencv-imgproc3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-image-publisher : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                               Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                               Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs3.2 but it is not installable
                               Depends: libopencv-videoio3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-image-rotate : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                            Depends: libopencv-imgproc3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-image-transport : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                               Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                               Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-image-view : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libopencv-highgui3.2 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libopencv-imgcodecs3.2 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libopencv-videoio3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-interactive-marker-tutorials : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                            Depends: ros-melodic-interactive-markers but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-joint-state-controller : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-kdl-parser : Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-laser-assembler : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                               Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                               Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-laser-filters : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                             Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                             Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-laser-geometry : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                              Depends: python-numpy but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-librviz-tutorial : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-nodelet : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-nodelet-tutorial-math : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-pcl-ros : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libpcl-common1.8 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libpcl-features1.8 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libpcl-filters1.8 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libpcl-io1.8 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libpcl-search1.8 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libpcl-segmentation1.8 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libpcl-surface1.8 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-pluginlib-tutorials : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                   Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                   Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-position-controllers : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-python-orocos-kdl : Depends: python-sip-dev but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-python-qt-binding : Depends: python-pyqt5 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: python-pyqt5.qtsvg but it is not installable
                                 Depends: python-sip-dev but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-qt-dotgraph : Depends: python-pydot but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-robot-state-publisher : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rosbag : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-program-options1.65.1 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-regex1.65.1 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
                      Depends: python-gnupg but it is not installable
                      Depends: python-pycryptodome but it is not installable
                      Depends: ros-melodic-rosbag-storage but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-rosconsole : Depends: libboost-regex1.65.1 but it is not installable
                          Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                          Depends: liblog4cxx10v5 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-roscpp : Depends: libboost-chrono1.65.1 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                      Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-roscpp-tutorials : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rosgraph : Depends: python-netifaces but it is not installable
                        Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-roslaunch : Depends: python-paramiko but it is not installable
                         Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-roslib : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rosmaster : Depends: python-defusedxml but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rospack : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libboost-program-options1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
                       Depends: python-catkin-pkg-modules but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: python-rosdep-modules but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-rosparam : Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rospy : Depends: python-numpy but it is not installable
                     Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rostime : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-roswtf : Depends: python-paramiko but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rqt-bag-plugins : Depends: python-cairo but it is not installable
                               Depends: python-pil but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rqt-image-view : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                              Depends: libopencv-imgproc3.2 but it is not installable
                              Depends: ros-melodic-rqt-gui-cpp but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-rqt-plot : Depends: python-matplotlib but it is not installable
                        Depends: python-numpy but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rqt-pose-view : Depends: python-opengl but it is not installable
                             Depends: ros-melodic-gl-dependency but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-rqt-reconfigure : Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rqt-rviz : Depends: libboost-program-options1.65.1 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                        Depends: ros-melodic-rqt-gui-cpp but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-rqt-top : Depends: python-psutil but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-rviz : Depends: libassimp4 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libboost-program-options1.65.1 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
                    Depends: libyaml-cpp0.5v5 but it is not installable
                    Depends: ros-melodic-interactive-markers but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-melodic-resource-retriever but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-rviz-plugin-tutorials : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                     Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-self-test : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-stage-ros : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                         Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-stereo-image-proc : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libopencv-calib3d3.2 but it is not installable
                                 Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-tf : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-tf2 : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-tf2-ros : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
                       Depends: ros-melodic-tf2-py but it is not going to be installed
 ros-melodic-theora-image-transport : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                      Depends: libopencv-core3.2 but it is not installable
                                      Depends: libopencv-imgproc3.2 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-turtle-actionlib : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                                Depends: libboost-thread1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-turtle-tf : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-turtle-tf2 : Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-urdf : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not installable
                    Depends: libtinyxml2-6 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-urdfdom-py : Depends: python-yaml but it is not installable
 ros-melodic-webkit-dependency : Depends: python-pyqt5.qtwebkit but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to concentrate on the error

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But never found a solution to install ROS. I used Synaptic Package Manager to fix and remove any broken packages and tried to unhold every package to get rid of the problem but nothing worked.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because Melodic is the ros distro for Ubuntu 18.04. As of present the most recent release is [Noetic](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic) which targets 20.04. The version of Ubuntu you're using does not currently have a supported ROS release, as such your only real option is to downgrade if you want ROS.

Comment: I'll add that there are other options besides downgrading, including running ROS inside docker, and using a 20.04 virtual machine for ROS dev work.